# Rails - error : _SSLv2_client_method (LoadError) - Expected in: flat namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-3, openssl

After trying to add angularJS to my rails app, I get some errors.
Trying to fixed this, I thinks more errors showed up. (yay!)

So I rolled back my angularJS setup, and one error is still here ->

```
    require': dlopen(/.../.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.0.2/openssl.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _SSLv2_client_method (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /.../.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.0.2/openssl.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

Pretty anoying because now this error show on all of my apps.

Anybody has an idea ?

Thanks !

system : OSX Yosemite

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error with 'bundle' and RVM and it turned out that my issue was related to my $PATH var not pointing to the version of Ruby I was using.

Try updating RVM to the latest version using:

```
rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
```

This will update $PATH and it worked for me.